# Touschscreen acting like mouse - Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 13

Tags: dell, touchscreen, xps

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my new dell xps 13, however it seems to treat any touchscreen presses as a mouse, so scrolling won't work as it acts as a mouse click and hold (so it just highlights text).

Does anyone know what might have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have an XPS 13, and here is my experience. *Depending on the app,* the touchscreen will work as a "touchscreen" or as a "mouse." For instance, in Google Chrome, my touchscreen acts as intended by default. In LibreOffice (Microsoft Word equivalent), it acts as a mouse and just highlights things without scrolling. In Firefox, the touchscreen also acts like a mouse by default. However, by installing [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/) addon (after installing make sure to enable it in the addon's preferences menu), I was able to get touch support working i.e. scrolling by using my finger.

Therefore, I'm going to end by saying that this is a problem that varies from app to app and will depend on how an app is optimized for the touchscreen. If there is a specific app you want touch support for, I suggest googling something like "'app name' touchscreen linux" and seeing what comes up.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I was using firefox which explains the lack of touchscreen functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have an XPS 15, and from my own experience it appears that the touch screen support is entirely dependent of your application and on your distribution/desktop environment. Apps like Chrome detect the touch screen scrolling just fine, but some application simply just use mouse clicks on touch. Even Gnome itself has issues between when to use it as a mouse, and when to treat it like a touch screen.

Simply put there is no *defined* touch screen experience for Ubuntu, or really at all for Linux. It all is based on the application providing support for it. At least for now.

My system for Reference:

> Dell XPS 15 9550
>
> Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10

Comment: Did you by any chance have issues with sound after a suspend/sleep?